# Issue with datatype nchar in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am using SQL Server 2008, Visual Web Developer 2012 and .net 4.0. I created a table in SQL Server and added some columns to it. I gave some columns the datatype `nchar(10)`.

Now my problem is that when I insert string of less than 10 characters as a value of the column type `nchar(10)` and when I fetched the value it inserts blank spaces to complete the 10 character string.

Means if I insert `"a"` into column of type `nchar(10)`, 
then when I fetch the value again I get back: `"a         "`

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: use varchar or nvarchar instead

Comment: Instead of changing datatype, is this not possible to solve this issue?

Comment: changing datatype is solution. you are using wrong datatype for your need and trying to change a **datatype**. which I think not possible. and even if it can be changed then you will face problems later. so keep it simple

Comment: `NCHAR(10)` is **defined** to do this - it's by design, it's how it is **supposed to work**. Either that's OK with you, or then you're using the wrong datatype. You cannot change the behavior of the existing datatypes - either that's what you need, or then you need to use a different datatypes

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this to trim the whitespaces:

```
SELECT RTRIM(CAST(col As NVARCHAR(10))) FROM test
```

Check out ***[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b697/8)***

Answer (score 3):

define the string as  `nvarchar(10)` it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change data type, then you will need to TRIM the space from the output

```
SELECT
   RTRIM("a      ") AS ColumnName
FROM MyTable
```

But this means every time you have to do this every place you are using the column. It is better to user VARCHAR(10) or NVARCHAR(20) where VAR... means variable length. So if your string is not up to 10 characters, spaces are not added

Final SQL

```
SELECT
   RTRIM(ColumnName) AS ColumnName
FROM myTable
```